# How do it retrieve User data from this database structure?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app for a school project. I want that when a student logs in they should see their data `(ID, NAME, SESSION, PROGRAM)` and when anyone of faculty logs in they should see data in faculty node. They can successfully login, just I don't know how to fetch different data for users belonging to 2 different nodes. I am fairly new to android and Firebase so any clear answer will be much appreciated.

This is my Database Structure:
[image]

Comment: Can you share some codes?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("USERS").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String id = ds.child("ID").getValue(String.class);
        String name = ds.child("NAME").getValue(String.class);
        String program = ds.child("PROGRAM").getValue(String.class);
        String session = ds.child("SESSION").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, id + " / " + name + " / " + program + " / " + session);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
02 / SA / MCI / SP17
```

If you want to get the data from the other node, just change the reference accordingly.